# why do I get an error with 'from scipy import random'?

Tags: python, scipy

I have installed scipy and getting the following back trace when importing the random module.

**from scipy import random**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'random' from 'scipy' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy-1.9.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/__init__.py)
```

Did I miss something else to install?

In case of being relevant this is on ubuntu 22 with python 3.10.4.

Comment: `scipy` doesn't have a `random` module...

Comment: Are you very sure? Could you check the scipy documentation at page 166 (marked 162)? There is a from scipy import random in the example there. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/scipy-ref.pdf

Comment: That PDF documents version 0.7.x, and was written in 2009. It is currently 2022, and the currently available version of Scipy is 1.9.1 as of a few days ago. If you try [searching](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/search.html?q=random) current documentation, you will see that `scipy.random` is not a thing.

Comment: In my primary issue it is pybrain which is getting this import error. Looks like pybrain needs an update then?

Comment: See the third line in https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/master/pybrain/structure/modules/gaussianlayer.py

Comment: From what I can tell from looking around, `pybrain` was also created in 2009, and has not had a new release since 2015 - and that release had a version number of 0.3.3. The `setup.py` for that project doesn't specify a version of Scipy at all, and itself requests a Python version of 2.5. The program in question is unsalvagably out of date.

Comment: (Also: if you are having problems running someone else's code, please don't represent it as an issue from trying to write your own code. In general, we don't do tech support here.)

Comment: Last I checked, `scipy.random` was still supposed to exist, and resolved to `numpy.random`, but that was in SciPy 1.5.4, so about 2 years ago. I don't know if the situation is different in 1.9.1.

Comment: In the past, SciPy imported the full `numpy` namespace into the `scipy` namespace.  The use of those names was deprecated some time ago, and they have been removed in the most recent versions of SciPy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scipy doesn't have random module which you can directly import anymore. as an alternative you can use random from numpy(scipy is built on numpy) like code below:

```
from numpy import random
```